# How can I use windows.devices.wifi API to check for WPS status and connection options in my C# wireless app?

Tags: c#, windows, wifi, wcf-security, app.xaml

I am creating an app to see all wireless networks and check every  current security but. I did this using windows.devices.wifi and it works fine, but, I don't know how i can see the if WPS is enable and the WPS (WIFI protected Setup) connection:

- Push Button
- PIN
- or Null

I know the windows.devices.wifi API has a part for WPS parameters but i don't know how.

I try use the Microsoft steps but I can't do it and in the network I can't see examples.